# Unable to change the class of a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I got into JavaScript and tried setting up the following scenario:

I have 2 Buttons on my Site (IDs are buttonWebdev and buttonUXUI), which should trigger an Action when they are hovered upon. If buttonWebdev is hovered upon, it should hide all p', h3's and imgs with the class "classWeb". I wrote this code to do it, but it doesn't work:

HTML:

```
<h3 class="classWeb">Editierbare Inhalte</h3>
  <p class="classWeb">Test</p>
<button class="buttonImg" id="buttonWebdev"><img src="./img/buttonWebdev.png" /></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById('buttonWebdev');
var classWeb = document.getElementsByClassName('classWeb');
button.onmouseover = function() {
  classWeb.className = 'webdev';

}
```

CSS:

```
.classWeb.webdev {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please use titles which actually reflect the problem or question so they can be searched by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `document.getElementsByClassName('classWeb');` this gives collection & to add classes you need to iterate over them & then apply classes.
2. `classWeb[0].className = 'webdev';` would reset class

either use `classWeb[i].className += ' webdev';` or `classWeb[i].classList.add('webdev');`

See below working example

```js
var button = document.getElementById('buttonWebdev');
var classWeb = document.getElementsByClassName('classWeb');
button.onmouseover = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < classWeb.length; i++)
    classWeb[i].className += ' webdev';
}
```

```css
.classWeb.webdev {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="classWeb">Editierbare Inhalte</h3>
<p class="classWeb">Test</p>
<button class="buttonImg" id="buttonWebdev">hover over me</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

First, since there can be more than one element with a given class on a page, `getElementsByClassName` returns a *list* of elements instead of a single element. You’ll need to perform your action on every element of that list, with a `for…of` loop, for example:

```
for (let element of classWeb) {
    element.className = 'webdev';
}
```

(`for…of` is relatively new, though, so you might have to use a regular `for` loop depending on your target browsers.)

After fixing this, you’ll run into another problem. When you assign to `className` like that, you’re setting the entire list of classes on an object. If the list of classes is `'webdev'`, it no longer includes `'classWeb'`. Modern browsers support an API to *add* a class without affecting the rest:

```
for (let element of classWeb) {
    element.classList.add('webdev');
}
```

The way to diagnose these sorts of problems is by opening up your browser’s developer tools, looking for JavaScript errors in the console, and looking at the state of the elements you’re trying to affect in the document tree.

Comment: Thanks! But what if I want to target all of the elements with the class "classWeb" and not just a specific one?

Comment: @iamflee_: Updated. Maybe it’d be more appropriate to just add the class to `<html>`, though? You could have your selector target `html.webdev .classWeb` instead. (That’s done with `document.documentElement.classList.add('webdev')`.)

Comment: `.forEach` gives error.. its not a method on collection it seems

Comment: the link you gave suggest It has support for version 51+ in chrome, but on latest chrome also its not working

Comment: @vinayakj: Yep, I overlooked that it was `getElementsByClassName` (DOM4 `HTMLCollection`) and not `querySelectorAll` (`NodeList`). Sorry.

Comment: cool.. actually my first choice was also `forEach` but I found it wasnt working.. same confusion here.. and thanks you cleared it..

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classWeb');
```

will give you a **LIVE** list of all the matched elements. That means that when you reassign the class like so:

```
classWeb[0].className = 'webdev';
```

the element will be removed from the list, as it no longer corresponds to the original command which was to find all elements with a specific class (which you overrode with **'webdev'**).

An easier and more friendly api is **querySelectorAll** which mimics the jQuery selector (which uses **css selectors** to find elements, thats why there is a **#** for an **id** and a **.** for a **class** name). The example below shows, how to use it.

```
var button = document.querySelector('#buttonWebdev');
var classWeb = document.querySelectorAll('.classWeb');

button.onmouseenter = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < classWeb.length; i++) {
      classWeb[i].className = 'webdev';
    }
}
```

ps. The querySelectorAll is not a live list, so items will not disappear after you change their class.

ps2. Use **onmousenter** instead of **onmouseover** as the **onmouseenter** is only called when the mouse starts hovering over an element, while **onmouseover** will be called on every mouse move over the element (even if already hovering).

Good luck!